# Update row field only when the parameter been supplied with a value (SQL)

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2012

I've a stored procedure like this

```
alter procedure sp_test
@p1 varchar(10)='',
@p2 int=0,
@p3 nvarchar(10)=N''
as
begin
    update mytable set p1=@p1,p2=@p2,p3=@p3 where mycondition
end
```

I'm calling this SP from .NET and if am not supplying parameter say `p2` in one call, this will obviously replace the `p2` cell with empty string. So how can we avoid that. Like if no value supplied for a field use the existing value in that column. That way? The number of columns in that table is very huge and I thought its not a good practice to have separate update query for different situation.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry Ive got an answer for my own question, sharing it with those who needs the same

I modified the SP like this

```
alter procedure sp_test
@p1 varchar(10)=NULL,
@p2 int=NULL,
@p3 nvarchar(10)=NULL
as
begin
    update mytable set p1=COALESCE(@p1,p1),p2=COALESCE(@p2,p2),p3=COALESCE(@p3,p3) where mycondition
end
```

So COALESCE did the trick and solved the issue I think. So in my tests if no value

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_test
(
    @p1 varchar(10) = NULL,
    @p2 int = NULL,
    @p3 nvarchar(10) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable 
    SET set p1= ISNULL(@p1, p1),
    p2 = ISNULL(@p2, p2),
    p3 = ISNULL(@p3, p3)
    WHERE mycondition
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE ... WHEN ...` e. g.

```
alter procedure sp_test
@p1 varchar(10)='',
@p2 int=0,
@p3 nvarchar(10)=N''
as
begin
    update mytable 
set 
p1=CASE WHEN @p1 IS NULL THEN p1 ELSE @p1 END,
p2= CASE WHEN @p2 IS NULL THEN p2 ELSE @p2 END,
p3= CASE WHEN @p3 IS NULL THEN p3 ELSE @p3 END 
where mycondition
    end
```

Also you can use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` in SQL Server.